# Nuxt3, Firebase problem when using the .env variables: Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key)

Tags: firebase, environment-variables, nuxt.js, nuxt3

In a Nuxt3 application there is a problem when I use the .env variables for Firebase.

When I initialise Firebase like this:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "string",
        authDomain: "string",
        projectId: "string",
        storageBucket: "string",
        messagingSenderId: "string",
        appId: "string",
        measurementId: "string"
    };
```

All is working well. But when I do it like this:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
       apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
       authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
       projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJCT_ID,
       storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
       messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
       appId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
       measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASURMENT_ID
    };
```

Firebase errors with: `Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key)`

I tried: `console.log(process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY)` and it returns the correct string. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use environments variable in Nuxt you have to use the `RuntimeConfig` option. The usage is explained [here](https://nuxt.com/docs/migration/runtime-config#runtime-config) and documented [there](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#runtimeconfig).

You have to define the existing variables in the `nuxt.config` file like this:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    // Private config that is only available on the server
    apiSecret: '123',
    firebase: {
        configOption: true,
        configSecret: ''
    }, 
    // Config within public will be also exposed to the client
    public: {
      apiBase: '/api',
      externalApiBase: ''
    }
  },
})
```

You set their values in your `.env` file by prefixing their name by `NUXT_` and the path to the value. Please note that the environment variables defined here will overwrite the defaults provided in the config file :

```
NUXT_API_SECRET=theverysecret
NUXT_FIREBASE_CONFIG_OPTION=false
NUXT_FIREBASE_CONFIG_SECRET=firebase-secret
NUXT_PUBLIC_EXTERNAL_API_BASE='https://api.external/com/'
```

You can then access the runtime config instance in your components like so:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const config = useRuntimeConfig()

// instead of process.env you will now access config.public.apiBase
console.log(config.public.apiBase)
</script>
```

and in your server routes like this:

```js
const config = useRuntimeConfig()

export default (req, res) => {
  // In server, you can now access config.apiSecret, in addition to config.public
  console.log(config.apiSecret)
  console.log(config.public.apiBase)
}
```

Ps: also note that for the Firebase privateKey you might have to replace the `\n` of the privateKey because of the way the values are parsed like so: `config.firebase.privateKey?.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')`